# php how to display my subcategories (xtemplate)

Tags: php

I'm using xTemplate class

My PHP codes:

```
$sql = $database->query('SELECT * from os_forumcats ORDER BY orderby ASC');
foreach($sql as $row):
    $template->assign(array(
        'FORUMS_ID'             => $row['id'],
        'FORUMS_TITLE'          => $row['title'],
        'FORUMS_DESCRIPTION'    => $row['description'],
    ));
    $template->parse('MAIN.FORUMS_ROW');
endforeach;
```

My Template Codes:

```
<table>
    <!-- BEGIN: FORUMS_ROW -->
    <tr>
        <td>{FORUMS_ID}</td>
        <td>{FORUMS_TITLE}</td>
        <td>{FORUMS_DESCRIPTION}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END: FORUMS_ROW -->
</table>
```

How to display sub-forums?

My table:

[image]

My categories

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following (not tested). PHP code can be:
**[Updating this code as per your comments]**

```
$sql = $database->query('SELECT * from os_forumcats WHERE parentid = 0 ORDER BY orderby ASC');
foreach ($sql as $row):
    $template->assign(array(
        'FORUMS_ID' => $row['id'],
        'FORUMS_TITLE' => $row['title'],
        'FORUMS_DESCRIPTION' => $row['description'],
    ));
    $template->parse('MAIN.FORUMS_ROW');
    $subquery = $database->query('SELECT * from os_forumcats WHERE parentid = $row["parentid"] ORDER BY orderby ASC');
    foreach ($subquery as $subrow):
        $template->assign(array(            
            'SUBFORUMS_TITLE' => $subrow['title'],            
        ));
        $template->parse('MAIN.SUBFORUMS_ROW');
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Template Codes:

```
<table> 
    <!-- BEGIN: FORUMS_ROW --> 
    <tr> 
        <td> {FORUMS_ID}</td> 
        <td>{FORUMS_TITLE}<br /> 
            <!-- BEGIN: SUBFORUMS_ROW --> 
            {SUBFORUMS_TITLE}, 
            <!-- END: SUBFORUMS_ROW --> 
        </td> 
        <td>{FORUMS_DESCRIPTION}</td> 
    </tr> 
    <!-- END: FORUMS_ROW --> 
</table>
```

Comment: I need the following
<table>
    <!-- BEGIN: FORUMS_ROW -->
    <tr>
        <td>{FORUMS_ID}</td>
        <td>{FORUMS_TITLE}<br />
  <!-- BEGIN: SUBFORUMS_ROW -->

        {FORUMS_TITLE},
     <!-- END: SUBFORUMS_ROW -->
  </td>
        <td>{FORUMS_DESCRIPTION}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END: FORUMS_ROW -->
</table>